# Getting All Users From Active Directory Groups Using Powershell

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I have a powershell script that I've written that gets all of the groups from an OU and stores them in a variable $groups.  I want to be able to access the users of each group but seem to be having trouble.  I've tried:

```
foreach($group in $groups){$get-ADUser $group}
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.
At line:1 char:33
+ foreach($group in $groups){$get- <<<< ADUser $group}
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

I am using Windows Server 2003 R2 on a windows 7 machine.  I'm pretty new to this so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The main problem with your script was that you put a $ in front of the get-ADUser command - $ is used for variables.  Also, as mentioned in the answer, you wanted to be using Get-ADGroupMember instead of Get-ADUser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To retrieve *only* the members that are users, and not groups:

```
foreach($group in $groups)
{
  Get-ADGroupMember $group | Where-Object {$_.objectClass -eq "user"}
}
```

If you want users who are members of the groups indirectly (through nested group memberships), user the `-Recursive` switch parameter:

```
foreach($group in $groups)
{
  Get-ADGroupMember $group -Recursive | Where-Object {$_.objectClass -eq "user"}
}
```

You can then assign the output to a variable for further use, like so:

```
$AllGroupMembers = foreach($group in $groups)
{
  Get-ADGroupMember $group -Recursive | Where-Object {$_.objectClass -eq "user"}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
foreach ($group in $groups)
{
    Get-ADGroupMember $group | select Name
}
```

`Get-ADUser` is looking for an Active Directory User object, what you're essentially trying to do is use that cmdlet on an Active Directory Group object.